# Exporting subset of data but maintaining relationship class properties within new file geodatabase using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, clip, relationship-class

I have created a script tool that allows the user to choose a spatial extent and export several feature classes within that extent and (what is supposed to be) a related table to a new file geodatabase.  Within the master database where the exports are coming from, there is a relationship class between one of the feature classes and the table.  I am unsure of the best way to maintain the relationship (or create a new one) so that the records in the exported table reflect the related records that were deleted during the spatial extent clipping.

I have attempted to export the feature classes and table and then create a new relationship class within the geodatabase.  When I do this, the relationship works for any records deleted manually afterwards.  However, there are still a bunch of records in the table (destination table) that do not exist in the feature class (origin table) because they were not updated when the relationship class was created.  I have also tried creating the relationship class in the GDB prior to copying the features and table into it - this gives the same result.

Is there a specific way to make sure a relationship class works retroactively?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Here is my code for this part of the script:

```
output = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace, gdb_name)
gdb = output.getOutput(0)

# make NHA_Core feature layer from selection and copy to new GDB
core_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(NHA_Core, "core_lyr")
core_selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(core_lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", '"STATUS" = \'C\' or "STATUS" = \'NP\'')
if len(clip_lyr) > 0:
    core_selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(core_lyr, "INTERSECT", clip_lyr, "", "SUBSET_SELECTION", "")
else:
    core_selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(core_lyr, "INTERSECT", interactive_selection, "", "SUBSET_SELECTION", "")
Core = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(core_selection, os.path.join(gdb, "NHA_Core"))
arcpy.DeleteField_management(Core, deleteFields)

Species = arcpy.CopyRows_management(NHA_SpeciesTable, os.path.join(gdb, "NHA_SpeciesTable"))

arcpy.CreateRelationshipClass_management(Core, Species, os.path.join(gdb, "NHA_Core_Species"),
"COMPOSITE", "NHA_SpeciesTable", "NHA_Core", "FORWARD", "ONE_TO_MANY",
"NONE", "NHA_JOIN_ID", "NHA_JOIN_ID")
```

Comment: What happens when you try simply clipping a feature class that participates in a relationship class?  I think you should do a separate test on that using some test data.

Comment: I tried clipping with the feature class that participates in the relationship class and got the same result - the table is still not updating unless I manually delete records from the origin table.